# WooCommerce product and terms count

Tags: plugins

I need to display two things:

1. Total number of published WooCommerce products
2. Total number OF attributes from a term

I can add this in account-bar.php Just need the required inbuilt Woocommerce codes.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get number of woocommerce published products -

```
$total_products = count( get_posts( array('post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'fields' => 'ids', 'posts_per_page' => '-1') ) );
```

To get attributes count -

```
$total_attribute_terms = get_terms('pa_'. $attribute_slug, array('hide_empty' => false, 'fields' => 'count') );
```

The `$attribute_slug` can be found on Attribute edit page - Wp admin -> Products -> Attributes -> click on fly-out menu `edit` (not name)

Comment: Hi Shazzad,

Thanks for the reply :) Can I just add this to account-bar.php file or should I use a hook?

Comment: You can add this to your account-bar.php file, just keep note to replace the $attribute_slug to a valid one.

Comment: Shazzad :) I just made some changes to the file, but it doesn't reflect on frontend. http://pho.to/4KTyT Please check the screenshot. Is there anything I am missing? Sorry, I am so noob in this.

Comment: write it like - 
`<?php _e('Samlet et sted: <b>'. $total_products .' text text text text '. $total_attribute_terms .' text text text </b>'); ?>`

Comment: You are a star mate! That did the trick :)